# Rename several unnamed columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, kaggle

I imported a csv as a dataframe from San Francisco Salaries database from Kaggle

```
df=pd.read_csv('Salaries.csv')
```

I created a dataframe as an aggregate function from 'df'

```
df2=df.groupby(['JobTitle','Year'])[['TotalPay']].median()
```

Problem 1: The first and second column appear as nameless and that shouldn't happen.

[image]

Even when I use code of

```
df2.columns
```

It only names TotalPay as a column

Problem 2: I try to rename, for instance, the first column as JobTitle and the code doesn't do anything

```
df3=df2.rename(columns = {0:'JobTitle'},inplace=True)
```

So the solution that was given here does not apparently work: [Rename unnamed column pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26098710/rename-unnamed-column-pandas-dataframe).

I wish two possible solutions:
1) That the aggregate function respects the column naming AND/OR
2) Rename the empty dataframe's columns

Comment: try this: `df3 = df2.reset_index()`

Comment: fantastic! that solves my problem, could you post it as an answer so we could give you credit? Thanks!

Comment: The first and second "columns" are actually panda Index objects. (Instead of 1, 2 ,3 ,4, 5, etc. numbering each row, you have a pair of labeled indices).   They don't operate the same way as normal columns.  Try `df2.index` to access them instead of `df2.columns`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting answer by MaxU:

```
df3 = df2.reset_index()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't really that you need to rename the columns.
What do the first few rows of the .csv file that you're importing look at, because you're not importing it properly. Pandas isn't recognising that `JobTitle` and `Year` are meant to be column headers. Pandas `read_csv()` is [very flexible](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with what it will let you do.
If you import the data properly, you won't need to reindex, or relabel.

Comment: OP asked about the `df2` DF, which is the result of the `groupby(['JobTitle','Year'])` operation, which results in `['JobTitle','Year']` multi-index. So playing around with `read_csv()` won't help

Comment: Ah, yes. My mistake.