# Pandas: Name the unmaed column of dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe that has one column but it does not have any name as shown in the figure below.

[image]

Now I want to name the unnamed coulmn. I looked at the existing thread ([Rename unnamed column pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26098710/rename-unnamed-column-pandas-dataframe)) and wrote the following code:

```
temp.rename(columns = {0:'SUBGROUP'},inplace=True)
```

but it didn't produce the desired result. Could anyone point out where am I making the mistake?

Comment: Looks like a `Series`, not a `DataFrame`, to me

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue. Indeed it is a series. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it needs to be clear that the Pandas Series is 1D data, the Series name is the column name you want, and it is displayed below when printed. If you want to get the effect that the column name you expect appears above the column value, you must convert the data type to the DataFrame type of pandas.

---

Demo

```
import pandas as pd

# build Series temp with first 3 row data of your example
temp = pd.Series(data=["DA33", "", "FK33-2"], index=[70015,69999, 69998])
temp.index.name = "SITE_NUMBER"
temp.name = "FEEDERID"
print(type(temp))
print(temp)

# transform type from Series to DataFrame
# you see the name of Series should beoome the column name of DataFrame
temp = pd.DataFrame(data=temp)
print(type(temp))
print(temp)
```

[image: Demo Display]

Comment: @user2293224，The pandas Series is 1D data, so there is no concept of columns. At this point, the name of the Series is the column name you want, and it will appear below when printed. If you want to use the concept of a column, that is, the column name appears above the column value for later data mining, you must first convert the data type to the dataFrame type of pandas.