# python pandas: how to modify column header name and modify the date formate

Tags: python, pandas

Using python pandas how can we change the data frame[image]
First, how to copy the column name down to other cell(blue)
Second, delete the row and index column(orange)
Third, modify the date formate(green)

I would appreciate any feedback~~

**Update**

```
df.iloc[1,1] = df.columns[0]
df = df.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
    
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.drop(df.index[0])

df = df.set_index('Date')
    

print(df.columns)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1 - How to copy *column name* to a column (*Edit-* Rename column)

To rename a column [pandas.DataFrame.rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

```
df.columns = ['Date','Asia Pacific Equity Fund'] 
# Here the list size should be 2 because you have 2 columns
# Rename using pandas pandas.DataFrame.rename
df.rename(columns = {'Asia Pacific Equity Fund':'Date',"Unnamed: 1":"Asia Pacific Equity Fund"}, inplace = True)
```

`df.columns` will return all the columns of dataframe where you can access each column name with index

Please refer [Rename unnamed column pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26098710/rename-unnamed-column-pandas-dataframe/54617685) to change unnamed columns

Question 2 - Delete a row

```
# Get rows from first index
df = df.iloc[1:].reset_index()
# To remove desired rows
df.drop([0,1]).reset_index()
```

Question 3 - Modify the date format

```
current_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
desired_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime(desired_format)
# Input the existing format
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], infer_datetime_format=current_format).dt.strftime(desired_format)
# To update date format of Index 
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,infer_datetime_format=current_format).strftime(desired_format)
```

Please refer [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for more details

Comment: Question 2: what I want to remove is the header of column, if I use `.iloc[1:]`, it would only remove "2nd" row. At finally, I wish to let the "Date" row be the column header.

Comment: Please try to rename the headers, and drop the columns you wish

Comment: Or please refer https://newbedev.com/python-pandas-dataframe-remove-header-row-code-example

Comment: When I try to do `df['Date']`, it gives me `KeyError: 'Date'` error

Comment: try to `print(df.columns)` and please check column name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236129/discussion-between-rinshan-kolayil-and-teri-ciu).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your questions. I mean, do you actually want to change the dataframe or how it is printed/displayed?
Indexes can be changed by using methods `.set_index()` or `.reset_index()`, or can be dropped eventually. If you just want to remove the first digit from each index (that's what I understood from the orange column), you should then create a list with the new indexes and pass it as a column to your dataframe.

Regarding the date format, it depends on what you want the changed format to become. Take a look into python `datetime`.

I would strongly suggest you to take a better look into `pandas` features and documentations, and how to handle a dataframe with this library. There is plenty of great sources a Google-search away :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the first two rows using [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html).
2. Rename the second column using [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html).
3. Work with datetime format using the datetime package. Read about it [here](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-format-dates-in-python/)